# Bi-directional one-to-many with inheritance not working (jpa with hibernate 3.5.4)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to map a bi-directional one-to-many relationship. I am having some trouble as the "many" side references an abstract superclass. While searching the internet for possible causes I discovered that this is a known problem but I wasn't able to find a solution for my case.

I have checked the workarounds on [this](http://chriswongdevblog.blogspot.be/2009/10/polymorphic-one-to-many-relationships.html) blog and the "Single table, without mappedBy" looks like a solution but I really need the bi-directional association.

These are the classes I am trying to map:

Owning Side

```
@Entity(name = "CC_Incl_Site")
public class IncludedSite {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "includedSite")
    private Set<CtaContractBase> ctas = new HashSet<CtaContractBase>();

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "includedSite")
    private Set<WoContractBase> wos = new HashSet<WoContractBase>();  
}
```

Other Side:

```
@Entity
public abstract class SCContract extends Contract {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "incl_site_id")
    private IncludedSite includedSite;
}
```

Contract (the superclass of SCContract):

```
@Entity(name = "CC_CONTRACT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "contractType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@ForceDiscriminator
public abstract class Contract {

...

}
```

When trying to run the application I get this exception:

mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: 
CtaContractBase.includedSite in IncludedSite.ctas

Another solution appears to be replacing the @Entity annotation in SCContract with @MappedSuperClass but this results in another exception (Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: StudyContract.contracts[SCContract]) because in another class (StudyContract) I have

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "studyContract", targetEntity = SCContract.class)
@BatchSize(size = 10)
private Set<SCContract> contracts;
```

and as the blog explains having a collection of the superclass is not possible anymore using this approach.

Are there any other workarounds or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association in `IncludedSite` is defined as

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "includedSite")
private Set<CtaContractBase> ctas = new HashSet<CtaContractBase>();
```

So Hibernate looks for an attribute of type `IncludedSite` named `includedSite` in the class `CtaContractBase`. There is no such field. The field only exists in the subclass `SCContract`. This means that only `SCContract` instances can be the target of this association, and the association should thus be defined as

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "includedSite")
private Set<SCContract> ctas = new HashSet<SCContract>();
```

Comment: I assumed this would work because of the basic principles of inheritance. This is documented as the way to implement inheritance in hibernate. So there is no way to map this in the way I expect it to?

Comment: Only SCContract instances can be part of an IncludedSite. So having a Set<CtaContractBase> to hold them is wrong, even if you put Hibernate aside. You could end up storing another kind of CtaContacrtBase in the set, which would be wrong, both on the OO level and on the relational level. You wouldn't put a steak in an egg box, even if both are food.

Comment: That's true for the case you present but in my case its more of a "Food > Meat > ChickenMeat" hierarchy where CtaContractBase is the "Meat" in the chain. In this case it makes sense to be able to put several kinds of meat in a set of Meat. If I use a set of the general class "Food" I would be able to put a "Carrot" in it while I really only need Meat.